# Proof that the module of section of a vector bundle and the module of section of the pullbackbundle are isomorphic.

Tags: category-theory, modules, vector-bundles

I put this question in math.stackexchange but since I had no answer

Let $\pi: E \rightarrow B$ be a fiber bundle with abstract fiber $F$ and let $f: B^{\prime} \rightarrow B$ be a continuous map. Define the  [pullback bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_bundle) by
$$
f^{*} E=\left\{\left(b^{\prime}, e\right) \in B^{\prime} \times E \mid f\left(b^{\prime}\right)=\pi(e)\right\} \subseteq B^{\prime} \times E
$$

Let $\Gamma(E)$ be the module of section of the vector bundle $E$ and  $\Gamma(f^*E)$ the module  of section for the vector bundle $\pi':f^*E\rightarrow B $

My goal is to proof that  $\Gamma(E)$ and  $\Gamma(f^*E)$ are isomorphic.

Define the map $\phi:\Gamma(E)\rightarrow \Gamma(f^*E)$
by $\phi(\sigma)(p)= \sigma(f(p))$ for $p\in B'$

This map is surjective since for a section $\sigma* \in \Gamma(f^*E)$ we can define the section
$\sigma  \in \Gamma(E)$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma(p)$ where $\{x\in B: f(x)=p, p \in B'\}$

How to proof that this map is injective?

Comment: you say $\sigma(x)=\sigma(p)$ where... where what? you just tried defined a set but did nothing with it, and $f(x)=p$ doesn't make sense. Also, you might want to consider the inclusion of a one-point space into $B$.

Comment: I will edit my question.

Comment: I think you should have accepted Alessandro's answer and asked a new question instead of completely changing the old one, since that edit of yours renders Alessandro's answer as something absolutely unrelated.

Comment: OK you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This map is neither injective nor surjective. As a counterexample, as pointed out in the comments, consider an inclusion $\{*\}\rightarrow B$ (which corresponds to the unique point $x\in B$ image of $*$), then the pullback bundle is simply $E_x=p^{-1}(x)$ and the map $\Gamma(E)\rightarrow \Gamma(E_x)\simeq E_x$ is simply "evaluation at $x$". A section of $E_x\rightarrow\{*\}$ is simply an element in the fiber (which is always non-empty) so $\Gamma(f^*E)\simeq E_x\neq\emptyset$, but there are fiber bundles without sections, so $\Gamma(E)=\emptyset$ (for example, take a non-trivial principal bundle, since in the context of principal bundles it is equivalent having a section and being trivial), so the map cannot be surjective.  On the other hand, can you see how the map $\Gamma(E)\rightarrow E_x$ need not be injective?

Comment: I will edit my question.